# Match object isn't being grouped

Tags: python, regex

I'm going to be writing a few regular expressions to output data in a specified format and so I created a little test regex which should output Jan, Aug etc. but the object doesn't seem to get grouped and so the output is always `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x028A6C28>`

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

kf = [s.strip() for s in open('keyword.txt', 'r') if not s.strip() == '']
sl = open ('syslog.txt', 'r')

keywordList = []

for keyword in kf:
    keywordList.append(keyword)

for string in sl:
    for keyword in keywordList:
        if keyword in string:
            print "**"+keyword+"**"
            datePattern = re.compile("^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]")
            dateResult = datePattern.match(string)
            dateResult.group(0)
            print dateResult
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         dateResult.group(0)
>         print dateResult
> ```

That's not how Python works.

```
        print dateResult.group(0)
```

or

```
        result = dateResult.group(0)
        print result
```

Comment: what if OP wants to print `dateResult` only?

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to python, I try to look around before posting here.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ...got it!